# Tensorflow installation issues

Tags: python, tensorflow

System information

```
OS Platform and Distribution - Windows 10
TensorFlow version: latest
Python version: 3.6.4
Installed using virtualenv? pip? conda?: - virtualenv
```

Greetings,

I hope this is the correct place to submit an inquiry of this nature, if it is not, please forgive my confusion & please point me in the right direction. I greatly appreciate your time & consideration.

I am new to Python & Tensorflow. I've done some coding with C in the past, mostly when I was in college. I am determined to learn Python & to utilize both Python & Tensorflow for AI & Machine Learning purposes.

I've had difficulties in getting Tensorflow to install properly. I started by installing the latest version of Python which didn't seem to like my attempts at installing Tensorflow, I then went with Python 3.6.4-amd64. I installed that, created a fresh directory for my environments, then installed pip & virtual env, then created a virtual environment to setup with Tensorflow.

One of the confusing issues I keep encountering is that when I install pip & virtualenv, and eventually Tensorflow, it keeps sending it by default to C:\user\username\appdata\roaming\python etc, my question is, how do I prevent it from doing that? I am trying to install in the direct being utilized in the command prop, I call up the fresh directory I created for my virtual environment, then activate the virtual environment, and no matter what I do it keeps sending all new install files into the appdata/roaming user directory sub folders.

This is causing the incredibly annoying issue of making it impossible for me to proceed with utilizing Tensorflow because I get nothing but errors on missing files, path directory etc etc. I even tried manually moving some of the files over to the virtual environment directory and that worked in some cases, but did not solve the overall problem.

Okay, now that I've made it painfully apparent how much of an uneducated newbie I am with all of this, may someone please give me some advice. The first step is admitting you need help, and I clearly do as I've spent several hours with my eyes glued to various articles and tutorials that have left me with more questions than answers. I truly appreciate any help you're willing to provide. Just a loner trying to figure this all out & increase my knowledge along the way. Thanks for your time,

Comment: for starters like you (especially on windows), I recommend using conda package manager. install miniconda on your OS. then follow https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/. its one-line command.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot. In addition, are you able to clarify how I can get my command prompt to stop defaulting installations to the user/appdata/roaming directory, it all goes there regardless of what directory I'm working in.

Comment: It really depends on which binaries are getting selected when you run python and pip(you can try putting complete path to executables in your virtualenv) . as I suggested conda handles this nicely. when a conda environment is active then it points these commands to correct binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Just moving the folder is not enough.

Once you have moved it, you must replace the original with a symbolic link to the new location. This will make windows think the data is still located on your C drive, while it actually is on your D drive.

Do note, this does work with AppData, but not with Program Files nor with the Windows folder, as it will break things like Windows Update.

To create the Directory Junction (Symbolic Link) do the following:

1. Open a cmd window with administrative privileges.
2. Navigate to c:\Users\username\appdata
3. execute the following command: `mklink /d local d:\appdata\local`
   replace d:\appdata\local with the actual path of where you moved the appdata to.

If you cannot move/delete the original copy, create a 2nd user, make it administrator, login with it, and retry the option. This should ensure that no files are in use.

With the above issue fixed, follow the tensorflow installation steps in Anaconda provided [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/).

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Joshua DeJonge - Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.